# No dropdownmenu options in typo3 backend

Tags: typo3, backend

I have an own extension started with extension-builder. Now I added a dropdownmenu in the backend. Unfortunately it has no entries to choose. My Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php looks like this:

```
    'ddOne' => array(
    'label' =>'My dropdownMenu',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'item' => array("1","2","hier 3","option 4")
        )
    )
```

I only get an empty dropdownmenu. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please have a look into the documentation, how to define items of a select-field in TCA: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html You need key-value-pairs...
P.S: Your field is missing a renderType.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into the documentation how to correctly create a dropdown, see: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html

`renderType` is missing and you need the values for your labels.